# Connect WP7 Mango to a Socket.io Server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to connect WP7 Mango to Socket.io? I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oren/archive/2011/07/07/getting-started-with-node-js-and-mango.aspx) page which contains an example on how to do that and indeed the C# client receives the response from the socket.io server.

But: Neither do I see that connection in the socket.io console (handshake, transport info and most important connection ID), nor do the events that I emit from the C# client trigger the related functions in the server script.

How do I have to encode the commands in the C# app in order to make them trigger the events in the socket.io script? In JS I would do:

```
socket.emit('something',{'foo': '123'});
```

What would be the equivalent in C#?

Thanks.